# Error creating bean with name 'loginController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDao';

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mybatis

I encountered the following problem when I started springBoot. I tried many solutions on the Internet but none of them solved my problem.

For example, I tried:

1. Add @ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.xrg.coursework.dao"}) in my code
2. The @NoArgsConstructor annotation is added to the class to construct a parameterless constructor

I just started to learn springBoot, this problem has troubled me for a long time, please help me to solve it。

The problem that I meet:

```java
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'loginController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDao' defined in file [/Users/kong/IdeaProjects/Coursework/target/classes/com/xrg/coursework/dao/UserDao.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'sqlSessionFactory' or 'sqlSessionTemplate' are required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at com.xrg.coursework.CourseworkApplication.main(CourseworkApplication.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDao' defined in file [/Users/kong/IdeaProjects/Coursework/target/classes/com/xrg/coursework/dao/UserDao.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'sqlSessionFactory' or 'sqlSessionTemplate' are required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'sqlSessionFactory' or 'sqlSessionTemplate' are required
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.mybatis.spring.support.SqlSessionDaoSupport.checkDaoConfig(SqlSessionDaoSupport.java:122) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean.checkDaoConfig(MapperFactoryBean.java:73) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DaoSupport.afterPropertiesSet(DaoSupport.java:44) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    ... 30 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

That's the code of my project

**LoginController.java**

```java
package com.xrg.coursework.controller;
import com.xrg.coursework.bean.User;
import com.xrg.coursework.dao.UserDao;
import org.mybatis.spring.annotation.MapperScan;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@RestController
@MapperScan("com.xrg.coursework.*")
public class LoginController {
    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String login(@RequestBody User user){
        User us = userDao.getUserByMassage(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
        System.out.println("user:" + us);
        return "ok";
    }
}
```

**UseDao.java**

```java
package com.xrg.coursework.dao;

import com.xrg.coursework.bean.User;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Param;
import org.mybatis.spring.annotation.MapperScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserDao {
    public User getUserByMassage(@Param("username") String username, @Param("password") String password);

}
```

**coureseworkApplication.java**

```java
package com.xrg.coursework;

import org.mybatis.spring.annotation.MapperScan;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude= {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@MapperScan("com.xrg.coursework.*")
public class CourseworkApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CourseworkApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**UserMapping.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper  PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="com.xrg.coursework.dao.UserDao">
    <select id="getUserByMassage" resultType="com.xrg.coursework.bean.User">
        SELECT * FROM easyproject WHERE
        username=#{username} AND password=#{password} AND state = 1
    </select>
</mapper>
```

**User.java**

```java
package com.xrg.coursework.bean;

/**
 * 用户实体
 */
public class User {
    private int id; //数据库中自增
    private String username; //用户名
    private String password; //密码
    private String email; //邮箱
    private String role; //角色
    private boolean state; //状态

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String username, String password, String email, String role, boolean state) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
        this.role = role;
        this.state = state;
    }

    //get方法
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public boolean getState() {
        return state;
    }

    //set方法
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public void setState(boolean state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", username='" + username + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", role='" + role + '\'' +
                ", state=" + state +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an implementation for `UserDao`?

Comment: The use of interface files is to solve the problem of multiple data access layers that may be connected to various databases, so that only the corresponding structure needs to be implemented, and this problem does not exist after Mybatis, so there is no need to write impl Interface file, using service+dao+mapper.xml is a better choice. And I had the UserMapping.xml.

Comment: So you are using MyBatis?

Comment: Yeah. MyBatis+MySQL. Everything is running normally, when I start the project after adding UserBean, LoginController and UserDAOMapping.xml, an error is reported

Comment: Never used `MyBatis`, so I am afraid I can't help you further. Sorry.

Comment: MyBatis needs a datasource, you are excluding hte datasource from being setup, no datasource, no mybatis, no dynamic implementation of the `UserDao`. No Bean, error during startup.

Answer (score -1):

If you try connect with JPA
In interface you dont need a @Repository and extends from JPARepository, like this:

```
public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<User,int>{
    public User findByUsername(@Param("username") String username);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don’t understand your suggestion very well, so can you talk about it in detail

Comment: The user is using MyBatis **not** JPA, so suggesting to use JPA isn't going to solve the problem.